# HTML place divs on same level

Tags: html

I currently have the following html page showing notification and alerts (models in my db )
[image]

Html code :

```
   {% extends 'users/base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}
<div class="dropdown dropdown-dark" >
    <select name="two" id="esite2" class="dropdown-select">
      <option disabled selected>Select Site</option>
    {% for site in thesites %}
        <option value="{{ site.id }}">{{ site.site }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
<br>
<br>


<div class="card-1">
<h1 style="text-align:center;">{{site_name}}</h1>
 <br>
    <div class="inline-block-child" >


{% for notification in on_track %}
 <div class="col-sm-12" id="parent2" >
 <div class="alert fade alert-simple alert-success alert-dismissible text-left font__family-montserrat font__size-16 font__weight-light brk-library-rendered rendered show">
 <i class="start-icon far fa-check-circle faa-tada animated"></i>
 <strong class="font__weight-semibold">{{notification.kpi}}
</strong>
 </div>
         <svg class="radial-green" data-percentage={{notification.value}} viewBox="0 0 80 80">
            <circle class="incomplete" cx="40" cy="40" r="35"></circle>
            <circle class="complete" cx="40" cy="40" r="35" style="stroke-dashoffset: 39.5841px;"></circle>
            <text class="percentage" x="50%" y="57%" transform="matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 80, 0)">{{notification.value}}%</text>
    </svg>


 </div>
{% endfor %}
         </div>

<div class="inline-block-child" >
{% for alert in alerts %}

        <div class="col-sm-12" id="parent">
        <div class="alert fade alert-simple alert-danger alert-dismissible text-left font__family-montserrat font__size-16 font__weight-light brk-library-rendered rendered show" role="alert" data-brk-library="component__alert">

          <i class="start-icon far fa-times-circle faa-pulse animated"></i>
          <strong class="font__weight-semibold">{{alert.kpi}} </strong>
        </div>


    <svg class="radial-progress" data-percentage={{alert.value}} viewBox="0 0 80 80">
            <circle class="incomplete" cx="40" cy="40" r="35"></circle>
            <circle class="complete" cx="40" cy="40" r="35" style="stroke-dashoffset: 39.5841px;"></circle>
            <text class="percentage" x="50%" y="57%" transform="matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 80, 0)">{{alert.value}}%</text>
    </svg>
      </div>

{% endfor %}

 </div>


</div>
<br>

{% endblock content %}
```

I would like to have employee satisfactionra rate go up to the level of turn over and suggestion implementation rate to go to performance appraisal completion rate.
I am new to css so please help me

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using BootStrap Grid System- which I can see in the code. You can simply use class=“row” to place divs under one another

Comment: Thank you @Rumjhum Singru putting the elements under a div with class="row" solved the problem !

Comment: Great! Would be glad if you accepted the answer

Comment: You can click on the check mark or tick near the answer to accept it